# count only case related tasks

Tags: soql, case, count

In this below query I want to get all the tasks related to a contact, related to a case or related to other object.

```
  Integer c = [SELECT count() 
               FROM Task 
               WHERE OwnerID =: oID 
               AND Status =: 'Completed'];
```

Additionally I want to get the count of tasks related to a case that have status 'Completed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use SOQL join to filter:

```
SELECT count() FROM 
    Task WHERE 
    WhoId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact)
    OwnerID =: oID 
    AND Status =: 'Completed'
```

Add more filters as required on `WhoId` or `WhatId`

Answer (score 0):

- Count of tasks related to a case that have status 'Completed'.

  `SELECT count() FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :caseId  AND Status = 'Completed'`
- Get all the tasks related to a case/contact/other object in a single query

  `SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE WhoId = :contactId OR WhatId = :caseId OR WhatId = :otherId`

Replace the id fields with corresponding record ids. If you want to get separate list of tasks, then break this query. Have a look at [Task Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_fields.htm&language=en&type=0).

Note: You would need to prepare set of caseId, contactId, etc before performing the query.